# JS How to get the object value from an array inside of an array inside an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

am trying to get the value from the json file

Here is a live codepen of what I am working on codepen.io/krm218/pen/vGvaNN

Here is a screenshot of my json file
or go to https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ky5s

[image: JSON]

I'm trying to retrieve the main-view, alt-view-1, etc.. from the images array.
I've been able to get the other values like description and id with this code

```
 $.getJSON("json.json", function(data){
  $.each(data.products, function() {
  $("#results").append(
   this["id"] + this["description"]
   );   
  });  
});
```

When I do  `this["images"]`, I get

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I get those values?

Comment: can you post the actual object as code?

Comment: `images` is another array, you can get those values the same way you're doing it with the other values, a loop and accessing the objects inside the array, and then the properties etc.

Comment: looks like you're coercing the image objects into strings. Are you using the `+` operator on `this["images"]`  somewhere?

Comment: Why do you have an array of objects that each have a different key? It would make more sense for `images` to be a single object with a key for each view, or an array of objects like `{ "view-name": "main-view", "url": "/images/..." }`

Comment: @adeneo So I just run the same code inside the append () ?

Comment: @Aweary yes, right now I am using the + operator. When I do this["id"] + this["description"] + this["images"], that is where that code shows up

Comment: hey @JordanHendrix , you can see the json  file at https://api.myjson.com/bins/4ky5s

Comment: try using JSON.stringify(this.images)

Comment: Here is a live codepen of what I am working on
http://codepen.io/krm218/pen/vGvaNN

@maioman how can I just get the main-view image though? See the codepen. thankyou.

Comment: http://codepen.io/maio/pen/jqdPeB

Comment: @maioman that worked. Thank you!!
It was this.images[0]['main-view']

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get in there:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/tawabe/1/edit?js,console)

```
var arr = obj.products;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var images = arr[i].images;
  for (var img in images) {
    console.log(images[img]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this go inside the each loop that I have ?
See code here 
http://codepen.io/krm218/pen/vGvaNN

Comment: well all you need to do now, is change var arr = obj.products to var arr = data.products, which I just tried in the pen and it works

Comment: I see! Thank you @JordanHendrix.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your JSON a little, so that the images are stored as an object (like an associative array) under your product object, so here's where I started with the JSON (I only added one product):

```
var data = {
  products:[
    {
      description:'Matte black',
      id:1,
      images:{
        "main-view":'/images/1/mainView.png',
        "alt-view-1":"/images/1/altView1.png",
        "alt-view-2":"/images/1/altView2.png",
        "alt-view-3":"/images/1/altView3.png",
        "alt-view-4":"/images/1/altView4.png",
        "alt-view-5":"/images/1/altView5.png"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

With them in that format, you can use the jQuery `each` function to loop through the images, with the parameters being the key name and value in the each function. You can build an image list of them (or use the values however) by looping and using k and v to print their key and value respectively:

```
$.each(data.products, function(){

  var imageList = $("<div>").addClass("image-list");

  $.each(this.images, function(k, v){
    imageList.append(
      $("<div>").addClass('image').append(
        $("<span>").addClass('image-name').append(k + " = "),
        $("<span>").addClass('image-url').append(v)
      )
    );
  });

  $('#results').append(
    $("<div>").addClass('product').append(
      $("<div>").addClass('product-id').append(this.id),
      $("<div>").addClass('product-desc').append(this.description),
      imageList
    )
  );
});
```

The results should appear like this:

```
1
Matte black
main-view = /images/1/mainView.png
alt-view-1 = /images/1/altView1.png
alt-view-2 = /images/1/altView2.png
alt-view-3 = /images/1/altView3.png
alt-view-4 = /images/1/altView4.png
alt-view-5 = /images/1/altView5.png
```

Here's a Fiddle demonstrating: https://jsfiddle.net/5yc733k4/

Comment: hi @mark.hch thanks for your response. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the json file structure so have to figure out how to do it the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

**this.images[0]['main-view']**  did the trick!